how to dynamic import a big util in vite
in my app, i use highlight.js to render my page, but this util is too heavy, so i need to use dynamic import to prevent it to block my page appear, i do it like this:
import { CSSProperties } from "react";
import MarkDown from "markdown-it";
import { convertUpper2UnderLineCssKey, htmlEncode } from "@web/util/html";

let markdown: MarkDown;

export async function createMarkdown({
  hlStyle = {},
  iconStyle = {},
}: {
  hlStyle?: CSSProperties;
  iconStyle?: CSSProperties;
}) {
  if (markdown) {
    return markdown;
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  const [_, hljs] = await Promise.all([
    (await import("highlight.js/styles/atom-one-dark-reasonable.css")).default,
    (await import("highlight.js")).default,
  ]);

  markdown = MarkDown({
    highlight: function (str: string, lang: string) {
      if (lang && hljs.getLanguage(lang)) {
        try {
          return getMarkdownCodeTemplate(
            hljs.highlight(str, { language: lang, ignoreIllegals: true }).value,
            str,
            hlStyle,
            iconStyle
          );
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
      return getMarkdownCodeTemplate(
        markdown.utils.escapeHtml(str),
        str,
        hlStyle,
        iconStyle
      );
    },
  });
  return markdown;
}

but when i deploy my app , i found that this util still load in my home page, though i doesn't use it in my homepage: i feel very sad about this, so i ask for help.
the way i import the 'createMarkdown' function like this, the 'MarkdownText' doesn't use in my home page
import { CSSProperties, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { copyText, htmlDecode } from "@web/util/html";
import { createMarkdown } from "@web/service/markdown";

function MarkdownText({
  content,
  hlStyle = {},
  iconStyle = {},
}: {
  content: string;
  hlStyle?: CSSProperties;
  iconStyle?: CSSProperties;
}) {
  const markdownDomRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const [hasInitMarkdown, setHasInitMarkdown] = useState(false);

  const markdownRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const [showCopy, setShowCopy] = useState(true);

  const handleCopy = () => {
    copyText(content);
    setShowCopy(false);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowCopy(true);
    }, 1000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasInitMarkdown) {
      createMarkdown({ hlStyle, iconStyle }).then((markdown) => {
        markdownRef.current = markdown;
        setHasInitMarkdown(true);
      });
    }
  }, [hlStyle, iconStyle, hasInitMarkdown]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasInitMarkdown) {
      const ref = markdownDomRef.current;
      let callback: (e: Event) => void;
      if (ref) {
        callback = (e: Event) => {
          const target = e.target as HTMLElement;
          const hljs = target.closest(".hljs");
          if (hljs) {
            const copySvg = hljs.querySelector("i.icon-copy") as HTMLElement;
            const okSvg = hljs.querySelector("i.icon-ok") as HTMLElement;
            const rawString = hljs.querySelector(".raw-string") as HTMLElement;
            copyText(htmlDecode(rawString.textContent || ""));
            copySvg.style.display = "none";
            okSvg.style.removeProperty("display");
            setTimeout(() => {
              okSvg.style.display = "none";
              copySvg.style.display = "block";
            }, 1000);
          }
        };

        ref.addEventListener("click", callback);
      }

      return () => {
        if (ref) {
          ref.removeEventListener("click", callback);
        }
      };
    }
  }, [hasInitMarkdown]);

  return (
    hasInitMarkdown && (
      <div className="relative">
        <div
          className="absolute right-[1px] top-[1px] px-[10px] py-[5px] rounded-[5px] bg-gray-300 bg-opacity-40 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer"
          onClick={handleCopy}
        >
          {showCopy && (
            <i className="icon-copy text-white w-[20px] h-[20px]"></i>
          )}
          {!showCopy && <i className="icon-ok text-red w-[20px] h-[20px]"></i>}
        </div>
        <div
          ref={markdownDomRef}
          className="w-fit max-w-[800px] bg-[azure] border border-solid border-[blue] rounded-[5px] p-[12px] text-[12px]/[16px] break-all"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: markdownRef.current.render(content),
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    )
  );
}

export default MarkdownText;


how do you import?

Please ensure that the code is posted in text format, and not as a screenshot.

i add the way about how to use the createMarkdown funciton
